# How to call this function through RJS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rjs

Function call from javascript

```
Test.show({title : "Text",body  : "Description" });
```

How can I call this function from RJS ?

```
page << "Test.show({title : "Text",body  : "Description" });"

page.call "Test.show", "{title : "Text",body  : "Description" }"
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape " to form valid function call syntax, for this you can use ' single quote like

```
page << "Test.show({title : 'Text',body  : 'Description' });"
```

or

```
 page << %{ Test.show({title : "Text",body  : "Description" }); }
```